# Как сделать имитацию нажатия клавиши?

Tags: python

Через WinAPI можно сделать `ctrl, alt, space , f1, f2` и т.д. Меня же интересует нажатие любой клавиши.

Модуль `SendKeys` не предлагать)

**Upd 1**

Собственно решил вопрос следующим образом:

```
import win32api, win32con
win32api.keybd_event(ord("s"), 0, 0,0)
```

Comment: Не пойму, а чем то SendKeys не устраивал?

Comment: Тем что его нету под версии выше 2.6

Comment: Понял. Я сразу и не догадался, т.к. - старовер. :)

Answer (score 0):

Существует такой прекрасный модуль как `pyautogui` - https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Для нажатия любой клавиши - `pyautogui.press('s')`, `pyautogui.press('f')`, `pyautogui.press('#любая клавиша')`

Для нажатия нескольких клавиш - `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'alt', 'space') # Так же можно использовать любые клавиши`

EDIT -- Для того что бы нажать `shift` или `ctrl` нужно использовать `pyautogui.keyDown('')`, `pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl') # Это работает как зажимание`

Что бы отпустить эти клавиши надо написать `pyautogui.keyUp('')`, `pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl') # Это работает как отпускание клавиши`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать модуль `keyboard`:

```
import keyboard


keyboard.press_and_release(# клавиша)
# или
keyboard.write(# текст)
```